# Move array key to end and reorder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edited for clarification

Reordering is automatic, so please ignore that question

I'm trying to take a value from an array and put it at the end of an array.

So in the array
Array ("A","B","C","D","E");

Move B to the end to get a result of
Array ("A","C","D","E","B");

Comment: Then, is the desired output the same as the input?

Comment: Why if you move 1 to the end of the array it turns into 5??

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove an item from an array, and then append it to the end of the array?

Comment: It would help if you used some JavaScript code to show us what you mean rather than English as your question is very unclear.

Comment: you should quickly improve the question, it's unclear to me.

Comment: end result shown is same as initial array. The point of this is being lost in poor explanation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, so I'm just guessing this is what you want to do.

```
var exampleArray = ['A','B','C','D','E'];

// remove the desired item, in this case it is the item at index = 1
var item = exampleArray.splice(1, 1)[0];

// append the item to the end
exampleArray.push(item);
```

The resulting array is `['A','C','D','E','B']`. The index (key) of `'B'` changed from `1` to `4` as a result of you moving it to the end.

For more info on the methods I used, check out [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, but this is what I was looking for thank you. In the resulting array, the keys would be 0,1,2,3,4 right?

Comment: Yes, the keys (indexes) of the items will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. The index of an item in an array is automatically assigned, so, for example, the fifth element will always have a key, or index, of 4. So, the index of the element `'B'` in my example has the index of 4 now, instead of 1, which it started with.

Comment: @forgiveness thank you, I'm still new to arrays and didnt know that.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could help. For more info on arrays, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array